# Primefaces rating component with JSF2

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to use primefaces 3.3 with JSF 2. When I try to access the page , the components are not getting displayed.

There are some JS error on the page.

Uncaught ReferenceError: **$ is not defined** :

Uncaught ReferenceError: **PrimeFaces is not defined**

```
<p:rating starts="10"/>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add h:head to your page. See;

http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html